# LDAP Script Help - Put ldapserach command results in single quotes

Tags: bash, shell

The following script works, but I need help with one change.  Right now using lday serach, and a little utility called GETPASS, this script will pull a listy users, from a specified context out of an LDAP directory, compare their LDAP password, to an unused attribute, If different, add it to the unused attribute called carLicense, and then send it in SHA 1 format, up our google APPS domain, with Google Apps directory sync.  The one problem, is that it when it returns the ldapsearch, it works fine with a user in this format:

```
cn=joebloe,ou=googletest,o=someorg
```

However, if the usename has a space in it like this:

```
cn=joe bloe,ou=googletest,o=someorg
```

the script will fail as it does not know how to deal with that space.  In this situations, a single quote, around the DN will solve the issue IE:

```
'cn=joe blow,ou=googletest,o=someorg'
```

However, I have tried to alter the script to address this need of mine, and I am failing miserably, please see a copy of the script in Pasetebin below.  Any help with be deeply and GREATLY appreciated, as this is currently my only stumbling block to success.

http://pastebin.com/htWxsNXj

Comment: "Pastebin.com is under heavy load right now :("

Comment: Please post a self-contained example that reproduces the problem *here*, not at an external site which may or may not be available.

Comment: How the script fails? Any error message? Replace she-bang path with `#!/bin/bash -x` - it would help you to debug the problem.

Comment: The problem is demonstrated here..but I didn't want to paste the whole script here for fear of pissing someone off.  The exact error, when running the script is: ldap_modify: No such entry "cn=username" invalid DN context(34 modifying entry "googletest,ou=someorg,o=myorg"  It does NOT like the space in the DN hense it the script wating quotes around the result BUT I cannot figure out how to do that within the script I have tried several ways such as "'$RESULT'" and ""$RESULT""  and "$RESULT", all of which none work, and I am not convinced this is the only place the script need to be modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first line of generating result file (in your pasting is line 66) with:

```
echo "dn: '$RESULT'" >> $SCRIPTPATH/gadspwsync.ldif
```

If it won't help, don't remove the file in line 75. Check the content, show us the first line, then show the expected content.

Comment: Show an error message when running with -x with some lines of context. Please remember about removing possible confidential data from this output (like passwords, etc)